# Why is my definition of signum well-typed?

Tags: haskell

I did the following class instance of Num:

```
newtype Natural a = Nat a deriving Show

toNatural :: (Integral a) => a -> (Natural a)
toNatural x | x < 0 = error "Negative"
            | otherwise = Nat x
              
fromNatural :: (Integral a) => (Natural a) -> a
fromNatural (Nat i) = i

instance (Integral a) => Num (Natural a) where
   x + y = toNatural((fromNatural x) + (fromNatural y))
   x - y = let r = fromNatural x - fromNatural y
           in if r < 0 then error "Negative"
              else toNatural r
   x * y = toNatural ((fromNatural x) * (fromNatural y))
   abs x = x
   signum x | (fromNatural x) == 0 = 0 --by error, I wrote 0 instead of (Nat 0)
            |  otherwise           = 1 --by error, I wrote 1 instead of (Nat 1)
   fromInteger = toNatural . fromIntegral
```

I am surprised that signum doesn't give a type error, and moreover signum (Nat 5) gives (Nat 1) instead of 1. I guess that an implicit coercion is applied, but I wonder why. Please, could someone explain this issue?

Comment: If you make something an instance of `Num`, then any integer literal, can be converted, it does so by implicitly writing `fromInteger` in front.

Comment: Heck you can even say `fromInteger x = 0`, and make all literals into infinite loops!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer literals like `0`, `5`, `24`, `(-3)` have type:

```
Prelude> :t 0
0 :: Num t => t
```

An integer literal can thus be converted to any type that is an instance of `Num`. If you write `0`, then implicitly you write [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) in front.

Since you thus define a `Num` instance for `Natural a`, an integer literal like `0` and `1` can have type `Integral a => Natural a` as well. Or as described in the documentation for `fromInteger`:

> Conversion from an Integer. An **integer literal** represents the application of the function `fromInteger` to the appropriate value of type Integer, so such literals have type `(Num a) => a`.

In a similar way you can make a type an instance of [**`Fractional`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Fractional) and *floating point literals* represent the application of [**`fromRational :: Fractional a => Rational -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromRational), and with the [**`OverloadedStrings`** extension [ghc-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) you can make it an instance of [**`IsString`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:IsString) for string literals. These represent than an application of [**`fromString :: IsString a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#v:fromString).